# Bootstrap navbar collapse is white/transparent when dropped down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing with the navbar in Bootstrap, in the hopes of making it a bit smaller than the standard version.

I'm not sure how I did it, but when the size of the screen drops down enough for the toggle menu button to appear, the background is white/transparent instead of the preferred blacker inverse color.

If you have a better way of making the navbar smaller, I'm open to suggestions.

Here's a link to the full code, but will include CSS here also: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbgdbo

```
.navbar {
  height:32px !important; 
  min-height:32px !important; 
  margin:0px !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding-top:0px !important; 
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
 }
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top:7px !important; 
  padding-bottom:7px !important;
}
.navbar-header{
  height:32px !important; 
  min-height:32px !important; 
  margin:0px !important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: none;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-toggle{
  margin:3px;
}
.socialIcons {
  max-width:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trevor**,  If you add the `navbar-inverse` class to this area of your code it will work as you want it to.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a>Join Us</a></li>
        <li><a>Our Mission</a></li>
        <li><a>KickStarter</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: This worked in changing the background color in the drop down menu, but now the navbar is back to its original height.

Comment: Hi Trevor, override that it in your custom css. When you do a Codepen/fiddle add full urls so your code works fully. Your codepen needs the jquery.min.js and the bootstrap.min.js to have the dropdown menu work. See if you can get the css override to now work on this.